# Using a hotkey in a specific program without pushing it

Tags: batch-file

I want to open a software namely OBS(Open Broadcast software) using a batch file and then automatically start recording without my interference. The hotkey I have set for recording is pgup but I dont want to press it and I want the batch file to automatically send the signal that the pgup key is pressed and the recording should start. How can I do this using a batch file?

This is the code I have used to start it.

```
@ECHO OFF
start /d "D:\OBS Studio\obs-studio\bin\64bit" obs64.exe
```

Thanks.

Comment: Fine. And what is your question? Learn [ask]!

Comment: My question is how can I tell OBS to automatically record at startup. I have tried the settings of the software and this option isn't available. SO I want the computer to initiate it by getting the signal that pgup key is being pressed without me actually pressing it.

Comment: So please [edit] your question and put all relevant information there; so potential answerers do not have to pick pieces from comments together...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you passing it through cmd when you can launch it directly from inside AHK using [Run](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)?

```
; Checks to see if you're running the script as admin
if not A_IsAdmin
{
   Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Requires v1.0.92.01+
   ExitApp
}

; The key you use to start/stop recording
startRec    := "PGUP"

; Path to your OBS exe
obsPath := "C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe"
; Splits path up int dir and file name.
SplitPath, obsPath, obsFileName, obsDir

; Closes any previously opened OBS instances
while WinExist("ahk_exe " obsFileName)
    WinClose, % "ahk_exe " obsFileName

; Run OBS
Run, % obsPath, % obsDir

; Waits until the OBS window has come up
while !WinExist("ahk_exe " obsFileName)
    Sleep, 1000

; Minimized OBS
WinMinimize, % "ahk_exe " obsFileName
Sleep, 1000

; Sends key to program to start recording
ControlSend, % "Qt5QWindowIcon2", {%startRec%}, % "ahk_exe " obsFileName

; Run your game here.

ExitApp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried this and its showing an error "Failed to find locale /en-US.ini".

Comment: Also, i am using run because I want to simultaneously run a steam game with the same file. So for example, I want the same file to run the game, OBS and give OBS the PGUP signal, all while I just double-click on the .bat file.

Comment: I made some revisions and posted it above.
I actually had to download the program and install it to understand how to set this up.

Everything is commented. Make sure you read through it and set your OBS path.
You'll also need to add a [Run](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command before `ExitApp` to launch your game.

Tested working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help and trouble that you had to go through to answer my query. Really appreciate it. It worked exactly the way i wanted it to. Thanks a lot :) :)